# What is a "field" in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am reading about "Extracting fields", but I was not able to find any information on what a "field" is on the Net.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/extract-field.html

What could be a definition of a PhpStorm "field", so I can understand its meaning?

Comment: Extract Field refactoring declares a new field and initializes it with **the selected expression**. That's what that page says

Comment: Yes, but what a "field" is?

Comment: Whatever you've selected.In the example the string `param_query` was selected and was therefore extracted as a field

Comment: Ok. So this could be "a" or 'echo "Hello World!";' or like 100 lines of code? It would be all a "field"? And this is how this "storage container" or functionality is called in the phpStorm?

Comment: If you try it with `echo "Hello world";` it will inform you it can't because that's not a correct expression.(So I guess the question you should be asking is what's an expression in PHP). With `'a'` it will work and make a new string property with value `a`

Comment: By the way an expression is whatever can be evaluated to produce a value.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was not able to find it on the Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Field" is a variable of a class. It can be a `static` or belong to an instance of that class. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751269/oop-terminology-class-attribute-property-field-data-member), it contains a discussion on the same topic.